# how to install cPanel?

Tags: server, cpanel, whm

To install cPanel & WHM on your server, run the following command:
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest

im a beginner and im kind of confuse about where to run the following command? can anyone tell me where to?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to login to your server via SSH as user root:

```
ssh root@IP_address -p port_number
```

Once you are logged in, run the following command:

```
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

This will start your WHM/cPanel installation which takes about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

do the following in the shell:

```
cd /home
rm -rdf installd  (ONLY IF YOU HAVE PREVIOUSLY INSTALLED CPANEL)
wget http://layer1.cpanel.net/latest
sh latest
```